# OSX: How to make GNU Find the default find inside scripts?

Tags: shell-script, find, osx

So I installed GNU find via homebrew. I then created an alias called "find" and pointed it to GNU find.

```
~
➜  alias | grep find
find=/usr/local/bin/gfind
tree='find . -print | sed -e '\''s;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'\'

~
➜  which find       
find: aliased to /usr/local/bin/gfind

~
➜  find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION FTS(FTS_CWDFD) CBO(level=2)
```

My problem is that inside a script (tried bash and ZSH), the script always wants to use the find command supplied by Apple when I use the "find" command.

Any ideas on how to fix? Thank you.

This is my sample script

```
#!/bin/bash 

source ~/Documents/environment-setup.sh
alias | grep find
which find
echo "running find --version"
find --version
echo "running gfind --version"
gfind --version
```

This is the output of the script

```
~
➜  ./test.sh
alias find='/usr/local/bin/gfind'
/usr/bin/find
running find --version
find: illegal option -- -
usage: find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
       find [-H | -L | -P] [-EXdsx] -f path [path ...] [expression]
running gfind --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION FTS(FTS_CWDFD) CBO(level=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

ZSH and BASH are different shell , so be careful you can have many differences . 
you have 2 problems in your example .

PROBLEM 1 : which

**which** is not builtin command in bash but in zsh is .
Because **which** is not a built-in command it can resolve aliases

you must use **type**

*type* is a builtin command in both

in **BASH**

```
MyMAC:tmp e444$ bash -l
MyMAC:tmp e444$ type which
which is /usr/bin/which
MyMAC:tmp e444$ type type
type is a shell builtin
```

in **ZSH**

```
MyMAC:tmp emas$ zsh -l
MyMAC% type which
which is a shell builtin
MyMAC% type type
type is a shell builtin
```

PROBLEM 2 : aliases

in BASH , aliases is not expanded in not-interactive shell by default ( script )

From `man bash`

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless

in ZSH  , alias are expanded

small examples with bash **b.sh** and ZSH **z.sh**

file  b.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -v
alias mysql='/usr/local/Cellar/mysql55/5.5.30/bin/mysql'
mysql -v

MyMAC:tmp e444$ ./b.sh
./b.sh: line 2: mysql: command not found
./b.sh: line 4: mysql: command not found
```

file  z.sh

```
#!/bin/zsh
mysql -v
alias mysql='/usr/local/Cellar/mysql55/5.5.30/bin/mysql'
mysql -v

MyMAC:tmp e444$ ./z.sh
./z.sh:2: command not found: mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Comment: If aliases are expanded in ZSH, then why doesn't it work on that shell? Thanks

Comment: i dont see a example with `zsh` in you description

Comment: The only different is I changed "/bin/bash" to "/bin/zsh"

Comment: which version of zsh are you using ?